# SQL Server 2016 - Catastrophic linked server error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, linked-server

I have an issue with connecting to a linked server from SQL Server 2016 to an Ingres 10.1 database via an Ingres 64bit driver ODBC connection setup - ODBC connection succeeds and the linked server connection test succeeds.

T-SQL used for testing has been:

select *
from openquery("linked server", 'select * from "table"')

Some tables come back fine although most tables retrieve the columns but have no data throwing the error:

```
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "" reported an error. Provider caused a server fault in an external process.

Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server
```

**If I change the select * to specific columns, I still get the errors.** I have tried changing the provider settings to "Allow in process" on/off; both settings still do not work. If I turn the above setting on i get the error:

The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.

```
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Also a stack dump is created within the SQL logs saying EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION.
```

I have played with the security connection settings of the linked server but no luck.

Any ideas fellow DBAs?

Comment: Out of curiosity, on a 'failing' table, what happens if you just select 1 column instead of select * (like an id value)?  If that succeeds, add another and another.   I've vaguely remember another post on this site where select * was causing this same kind of problem, but I can't find the post.  If you can't even select 1 simple column from a failing table, I guess we're back to square one.

Answer (score 1):

If you get a stack dump, it's time to contact the author of the linked server driver and start a support call. That's not something you can fix via query changes or configuration.